# Node Mysql query with incremental variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, facebook-messenger-bot

I have problem why my variable in query dont increment? 
My code:

```
function processMessage(event) {
    if (!event.message.is_echo) {
        let message = event.message;
        let senderId = event.sender.id;

    console.log("Received message from senderId: " + senderId);
    console.log("Message is: " + message);
    console.log();
    var user = {
        user_name: '',
        question_index: 0,
    }


    if (message.quick_reply.payload === 'Pass') {
        connection.query("SELECT text FROM quiz_questions WHERE quiz_id = ?", [question_index], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            let jsonQuestionResult = getRealResults(results);
            connection.query("SELECT text FROM question_option WHERE quiz_question_id = ?", [question_index], function(error, results, fields) {
                if (error) throw error;
                let jsonAnswerResult = getRealResults(results);
                console.log(jsonAnswerResult[0]);
                sendQuestionAnswer(senderId, jsonQuestionResult[0].text, jsonAnswerResult[0].text, jsonAnswerResult[1].text, jsonAnswerResult[2].text);
                user.question_index++;
            })
        })
    }
}
}
```

I increment user.question_index but it doesnt apply when i call processMessage function what is wrong there? Or how to make that when i call quick reply with payload(pass) it will show next column from database?

Comment: Database queries are not synchronous in node.js. Your `user.question_index` is likely being incremented, just not when you think it is.

Comment: So where i should increment user.question_index to get next question process looks like that start->yest(payload=pass)->1question->1answer(payload=pass)->2question->2answer(payload=pass) so i call this func over and over as quiz going on ;)

Comment: Actually I didn't read your code carefully enough. The answer is correct. You will still have synchronization issues though: if two successive calls come in before the first completes you'll read the wrong value. Strongly suggest you rethink your design.

Comment: Hmm can you help me with it im trying to do simple quiz bot on messenger and i dont really know how design it properly.

Comment: First step to engineering anything is thinking about failure modes. In this case your failure mode is that you cannot count on the database query to finish before the next call comes in and reads the (unincremented) variable. Concurrency is hard, and anything working over a network is concurrent. Just make it so the user can't answer the next question until the first gets checked.

Comment: User cannot answer next question because he have to choose question in quick_replays. But i dont know how to check if answer is correct... i have in database field called "is_correct" so i just need to pass it to payload and check if it true and add score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your user variable outside the processMessage. Everytime you call the method it gets reinitialised to default 0. So If you want to persist the value

```
var user = {
        user_name: '',
        question_index: 0,
    }


function processMessage(event) {
    if (!event.message.is_echo) {
        let message = event.message;
        let senderId = event.sender.id;

    console.log("Received message from senderId: " + senderId);
    console.log("Message is: " + message);
    console.log();



    if (message.quick_reply.payload === 'Pass') {
        connection.query("SELECT text FROM quiz_questions WHERE quiz_id = ?", [question_index], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            let jsonQuestionResult = getRealResults(results);
            connection.query("SELECT text FROM question_option WHERE quiz_question_id = ?", [question_index], function(error, results, fields) {
                if (error) throw error;
                let jsonAnswerResult = getRealResults(results);
                console.log(jsonAnswerResult[0]);
                sendQuestionAnswer(senderId, jsonQuestionResult[0].text, jsonAnswerResult[0].text, jsonAnswerResult[1].text, jsonAnswerResult[2].text);
                user.question_index++;
            })
        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Although correct note that there is still a race condition.

Comment: Yes there is race condition as the calls are asynchronous. We can pass the response to a callback method which will increment the value.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related but may help others as there is lack of information on how to increment after select.

```
const select_query = pool.execute('SELECT * FROM `some_table` 
    WHERE `some_id` = ?', [some_variable], function(err, row) {
            
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return;
            
                } else {
            
                    if (row && row.length) {
            
                        current_count = row[0].column_to_update
                        new_count = current_count + 1
            
                        const update_query = pool.execute(
                            "UPDATE some_table SET column_to_update = ?", [new_count])
            
                    }
                }
            });
```